# returning a row from a procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a stored procedure in mySQL that returns contact info for people based on an approximate match: say someone you were talking with, but their name is spelled unconventionally and you don't remember their full phone number.

I borrowed some code from a friend who uses Oracle's SQL, which looked something like:

```
create procedure getPNrecbyID (in phone_number VARCHAR2,
                        in name VARCHAR2,
                        out target person_contact%rowtype)
...
```

But MySQL doesn't have the "%rowtype" syntax. Returning a primary key doesn't necessarily work, because what I want to return is spread over a few tables (person; phone number, which has a foreign key constraint on person, but I only want one phone number; and email, same thing as phone number. Person_contact is a view).

Is there any way to return the equivalent of "%rowtype" of a view (or table; I won't like it, but I can find a way to make it work); should I just return (possibly inout) enough variables (annoying, but doable); or is there another way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this syntax - not just select as LAST line of procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure getPNrecbyID (in phone_number VARCHAR2, in name VARCHAR2) READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
select * from table;
END$$
```

Comment: A couple clarifying questions:

1) Where does my code (the '...' in my question) go?
2) If I just close the procedure with a select statement, it will return that?

Comment: you code goes after BEGIN before last SELECT, last SELECT statement is what stored procedures returns results of this select to caller

Comment: Okay, now how do I make use of the results? 

For example, I just sold something to "John Doe with phone number 123-4567"; I need to send him an email thanking him for his purchase with the right spelling and honorifics, and want that email to auto-generate. Is there any way to get the information out of the query in a procedure calling 'getPNrecbyID'?

Comment: I don't understand you, you cannot send email from stored procedure, you have to write some script (propably php) which will execute query which will run procedure, got results, format them and send e-mail

Comment: Sorry, mixing parts of my code. I want to be able to go through the data, or example if I get multiple results, but only want one (There's two "John Doe"s here, one in area code 123 and the other in area code 234); and to otherwise take further action on the data (okay, I'm interested in the one in area code 123: add the new order to the order table which has a foreign key to people).